# How can I use the ImageDraw module for a class which is initialised using an Image object

Tags: python-3.x, class, python-imaging-library

I am new to classes and I wanted to make drawing class for some image manipulation.I am doing this with the ImageDraw module  in PIL.
I initialised the draw attribute using an Image object and then tried to draw over the image using ImageDraw. However I couldn't get any results.It would be great if someone told me where I messed up

```py
#shapemakers.py
import PIL
from PIL import ImageDraw
import random

class drawings():

    def __init__(self,img):
        self.image=img
        self.draw=ImageDraw.Draw(self.image,'RGB')

    def circledraw(self,x,y,r):
        cord1_x=x-r
        cord2_x=x+r
        cord1_y=y-r
        cord2_y=y+r
        return((cord1_x,cord1_y,cord2_x,cord2_y)

    def arcer(self):
        x=0
        y=36
        while x<360:
            p=random.randint(60,120)
            self.draw.arc(self.circledraw(360,821,60), x, y, 'red',width=20)
            self.draw.pieslice(self.circledraw(360,821,p), x+36, y+36, 'yellow',width=1)
            x=y+36
            y=x+36
        return self.image
```

This is how I use the class

```py
import PIL
import shapemakers
newimg=PIL.Image.open('infocard-fm1.png')
newdrawing=shapemakers(newimg)
p=newdrawing.arcer()
p.show()
```

There should be  pie shapes and partly cut circle shapes on the image ,But all I am getting is a blank white image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are just a couple of minor issues, I can see.

I would replace this line:

```
newimg=PIL.Image.open('infocard-fm1.png')
```

with

```
newimg=PIL.Image.open('infocard-fm1.png').convert('RGB')
```

so that you don't get a *"mode mismatch"* if you load a palette-based image one day. In general, if you are expecting an `RGB` mode image, you should convert to `RGB`, otherwise you will get problems with palette images and images with alpha channels.

---

You are missing a closing parenthesis on this line:

```
return((cord1_x,cord1_y,cord2_x,cord2_y)
```

---

You need to replace this line:

```
newdrawing=shapemakers(newimg)
```

with:

```
newdrawing=shapemakers.drawings(newimg)
```

---

Then you get this result:

[image]